# Getting NoneType while trying to get updated date from RSS using python

Tags: python, datetime, date, rss

I have the following code which works well when I try to get the date from any RSS feed(Using Universal feed Parser):

```
for entry in RSS_FEED.entries:
    FEED_DATE=entry.updated_parsed
    FEED_DATE_STRING = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(FEED_DATE))
    FEED_DATE_STRING = str(FEED_DATE_STRING)
    FEED_DATE_STRING = Datetime.ParseDate(FEED_DATE_STRING).strftime('%a %b %d, %Y')
```

But while parsing the following RSS format:

```
<item>
<title>Title</title>
<description>
Description
</description>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 5 Oct 2011 03:11:00:00 +0700</lastBuildDate>
<pubDate>Wed, 5 Oct 2011 03:11:00:00 +0700</pubDate>
</item>
```

I am getting the error in Log file:

> FEED_DATE_STRING = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(FEED_DATE))
>   TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not None

Comment: Why are you initializing `FEED_DATE` to `None`?

Comment: @MattFenwick, Edited . Just to be sure that was NoneType , for testing

Comment: How are you parsing the feed?

Comment: @Avaris, I am parsing the feed using Universal feed Parser

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the [feedparser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) package to parse the rss: the reason for the error in the log file is that you are using a date format that feedparser does not understand. This means `entry.updated_parsed` will get set to `None`. The problem seems to be the fourth element in the time field. If the dates are changed to:

```
Wed, 5 Oct 2011 03:11:00 +0700
```

then feedparser handles them correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. But how do I convert it to date time format

Comment: @Subhen. What rss feed produces dates in that format? If the dates aren't in a standard format, you may have to take the date string from `entry.updated` and parse it yourself.